# Return to List View after using custom "Create Record" button on List View

Tags: list-view

I have a "Create Record" button on a Lightning list view.  It creates the record in the custom object when the user hits Save and then puts the user on a view of the newly created record.  Instead of this, I would like the user returned to the List View where the button was called.  We have Salesforce Professional.

Comment: what kind of button it is? Can you add more details about the button you have?

Comment: The button was created by going to my custom object in Lightning and selecting Buttons/Links/Actions.  I then chose New Button/Link.  I selected List button and gave the button a link, label, description.  I selected URL as the button Content Source and "Display in existing window with sidebar."  I then added the button to the Classic Search default list view.  The URL that I used is the one that comes up when I click New on the custom object's List View.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, You need the Return URL parameter in button URL. A sample example is below:-

```
/a06/e?retURL=/001/o
```

If you are working with Lightning URL Hack, below formula will work. It has backgroundContext that works same as Return URL parameter.

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Account/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&uid=160510799526966038&backgroundContext=/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=Recent')}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how I would modify the following button URL if I want it to create a new record and return to the List View from which I clicked the button?

https://na75.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/DC_Event_Member__c/new?count=3&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&uid=160506448009646530&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fo%2FDC_Event_Member__c%2Flist%3FfilterName%3D00B1K00000AUgdOUAT

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer check the update in answer.